# Filtering among Exposed Filters: Parent/Child relationship between two Exposed Filter in Drupal View

Tags: ajax, filter, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I wanted to make a page with `exposed filter` search app in Drupal for a list of people.

I started by creating content type `Bio` and populated it as following:-

[image]

Then, I continued making a view with exposed filters of the fields of content type `Bio`. With the help of `Better Exposed Filters`, I am showing both Filters through Checkboxes through AJAX, as below:-

[image]

Now, uptil now, it's working fine. when I select a region or/and any city, the content updates according to that.

What I am hoping to create is a dependency between the `region` and `city`. All I want is that when I select any region in the `Filter by Region`, the lower filter values in the `Filter by City` automatically adjust and show me only the cities for which the `region field` in `Bio` is the selected city.

As an example, If a user selects `EMEA`, the `city` exposed filters should only show European cities.

I have been stuck in this for hours now. I have tried various solutions (`View Dependent Filters`and `Filter Fields`) but to no avail.

Comment: Did you check the [views_hacks](https://drupal.org/project/views_hacks) module and its views_filters_selective option? Also you should better use something like [hierarchical_select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) to create the taxonomy tree (I suppose you used taxonomy for Region and City).

Comment: Thank you Theodor. I used views_hacks module.

Comment: I will write it as an answer so that exists on the search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [views_hacks](https://drupal.org/project/views_hacks) module and its views_filters_selective option.